# geom_smooth with hypothetical inverse exponential fit

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, exponential

Take the following code, I can generate a simple histogram:

```
A <- c(rep(0,200),rep(1,1000),rep(2,200),rep(3,100),rep(4,50),rep(5,10))
B <- c(rep("Apple",200),rep("Orange",1000),rep("Pear",200),rep("Grape",100),rep("Banana",50),rep("Nuts",10))

df1 <- data.frame(A,B)


library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df1, aes(A)) + 
  geom_bar() + theme_bw() +
  ylim(0, 1500) 
g
```

How can I add an red dashed line of fit to pass through points (A=1,y=2000), (2,200), (3,100), (4,50), (5,10) without changing the y limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data in the question, named `df2`, the solution is to define a function `f` with `approxfun` and then have `stat_function` draw its graph.

```
library(ggplot2)

f <- approxfun(df2$A, df2$B, rule = 2:1)

ggplot(df1, aes(A)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme_bw() +
  stat_function(fun = f, color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1500))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df2 <- list(c(1,2000), c(2,200), c(3,100), c(4,50), c(5,10))
df2 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df2)
names(df2) <- c('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new data.frame:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(A=0:5, B=c(0, 2000, 200, 100, 50, 10))
```

For the sake of completeness I included also `A = 0`. Now let's plot the graph:

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(A)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=A, y=B, color="red")) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1500))
```

The key is using `coord_cartesian`, which rescales the y-axis without dropping the data, instead of `ylim`. This gives you

[image]

Comment: @lukeg I realised that this doesn't answer the question since I ignored the "geom_smooth"-part. I will delete this answer soon, but perhapt the `coord_cartesian`-part solves your problem.